# Files appear twice in quick open list

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode for java and c++ projects.
In both cases, when I want to open a file with quick open (ctrl+P) the file appears twice.

- One time marked as 'recently opened' with relative path to my workspace and
- A second time with an absolute path in home (~/home/harri/...)

It seems as vscode manages the files twice generally. I think so because if I opened a file from project explorer and go to a methods definition (command: Go to Definition | F12) then the file is opened a second time. I can see in the files editor tab that the paths do differ. One relative path one with absolute path.

Is this a problem of my settings?

I am running vscode 1.74.3

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Is this really about a program you're writing, in Java or C++? Or is it an issue with the Visual Studio Code editor only?

Comment: Yes, you are write it is not a ajva/c++ problem but an visual studio code topic. Labels are already corrected.
But besides that the question is valid?